# Mysql COUNT, not counting as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, while-loop

I am using the following script to count records, the way I think it should be working should be.

'some heading'
x4

but instead it is outputting
'some heading'
1x
1x
1x
1x

```
    include("connectmysqli.php"); 
    if (isset($_GET['questionnaireID'])) {$questionnaireID = $_GET['questionnaireID'];}else {$questionnaireID = '';}
    echo '<p><strong>View Questionnaire Results</strong></p>';

    $sql1 = <<<SQL
        SELECT answer1, COUNT(answer1)
        FROM `QuestionnaireAnswers`
        WHERE questionnaireID='$questionnaireID'
        GROUP BY answer1
    SQL;
    if(!$result1 = $db->query($sql1)){ die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');}

    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()){ 

    echo $row1['COUNT(answer1)'] . ' X <strong>' . $answer1 . '</strong><br />';
    }
```

Here is an example of the table
[image]

So using the above screen shot, the column answer1 when counted should be 2x , but what is actually displayed is 1x 1x

If I run the query from the answers in phpmyadmin I get :

[image]

Comment: What is the table definition for `QuestionnaireAnswers` as well as some sample data?

Comment: Ok Iv added a screen shot of the table

Comment: Try fire the same query directly into phpmyadmin & check what result you are getting.

Comment: Ok I have added the results of that above

Comment: You are selecting the grouped field, you alrady have 2 different values for group by, 8 is not 2, so its right you'll get 1 and 1, if you have the answer 2 twice, then count of 2 will be 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to use a MySQL function (`COUNT`) in PHP. I have never seen such a usage. 
Use alias for count of answer1:

```
$sql1 = <<<SQL
    SELECT answer1, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM `QuestionnaireAnswers`
    WHERE questionnaireID='$questionnaireID'
    GROUP BY questionnaireID
SQL;
```

Then after `fetch_assoc()` method use it as

```
 echo $row1['cnt'];
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but it still comes up with 1x 1x

Comment: then do what Ollie Jones says. I have changed the code.

Comment: I still get 1x 1x, if I run it in phpmyadmin I get 
answer1 with 2 in one row and 6 in the other row, then another column called cnt1 with a 1 in one row and then another one under that in the other row.

Comment: I have added a screen shot above.

Comment: It is because of `GROUP BY answer1`. If you remove it you will get what you need. Or you can group it by `questionnaireID`

Comment: Thanks !, thats got it now ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(answer1)` and you should be OK.

This is smart for two reasons: first, it can be a lot faster, and second, you're grouping by `answer1` so you shouldn't count it.

*Edit* This is a summary query.

```
    SELECT answer1, COUNT(*) AS cnt1
      FROM `QuestionnaireAnswers`
     WHERE questionnaireID='$questionnaireID'
  GROUP BY answer1
```

It produces one row for each distinct value of `answer1`, showing how many occurrences of that row are in the original table.   The sample data you've shown contains just two rows.  One of them has an answer of 2, the other has an answer of 8.

Comment: I still get 1x 1x, if I run it in phpmyadmin I get 
answer1 with 2 in one row and 6 in the other row, then another column called cnt1 with a 1 in one row and then another one under that in the other row.

Comment: I have added a screen shot above.

Comment: You get a `6`?  Really? I am sorry, I don't understand this comment at all.